# Connection between chromatic number and independence number of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is it true that one can always colour a graph G with $\chi(G)$ colours in such a way that one of the colour classes is a maximum possible cardinality independent set? Please prove if it's true.

[Note: $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of G, or the smallest number k such that we can colour the graph G with k colours. Independent set means none of the vertices in the set are adjacent.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not true.  Please accept this humble paint counter-example.

[image: counter-example]

On the left, we see that the graph is 3-colorable.  On the right, we take the maximum cardinality independent set and make it all blue, then get stuck with the remaining two colors.

Comment: Awesome counter-example! Thanks!